# Terminal/Putty showing control characters (^M) after updating

Tags: text-editor, user-profile, special-characters, vi

I updated my system yesterday afternoon using the recommended updates from Update Manager.  After it completed, I shutdown my system and went home for the day.

I come in this morning and I am getting control characters displayed when using vi in both the standard terminal emulator, putty, and putty inside of my Windows virtual that I run with VirtualBox.  I have made no other system changes and I cannot figure out how this occurred.  It's as if every text file I have was created in DOS.

I've searched the forums and I haven't found any answers.  I am using `xterm` as my emulator and I checked with 3 of my coworkers and none of them are having this problem so we do not believe it is a server side issue.  Especially since I've checked 3 different servers.

There's nothing in my `.profile` other than `PATH` variables so I'm using the same terminal settings as everyone else.  Some files are fine (I can open and read both `/etc/environment` and my `.profile`) but most of any kind of server generated log file is trash.  Running cat or head on the same file displays the contents without the characters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure for the reason, but you can type inside vi(m) [in ESC mode]

```
%s/^M//g
```

to remove the CTRL M from a file.